# Docker for symfony and nginx without mounting the source code

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx, docker-compose, volume

We have a develop and a production system that use symfony 5 + nginx + MySQL services running in  a docker environment.
At the moment the nginx webserver runs in the same container as the symfony service because of this issue:

- On our develop environment we are able to mount the symfony sourcecode into the docker container (by a docker-compose file).
- In our production environment we need to deliver containers that contains all the source code inside because we must not put our source code on the server. So there is no folder on the server from which we can mount our source code.
  Unfortunately nginx needs the sourceode as well to make his routing decisions so we decided to put the symfony and the nginx services together in one container.

Now we want to clean this up to have a better solution by run every service in its own container:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    php:
        image: docker_sandbox
        build: ../.
        ...
        volumes:
            - docker_sandbox_src:/var/www/docker_sandbox // <== VOLUME
        networks:
            - docker_sandbox_net
        ...
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
        ...
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/server.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
            - docker_sandbox_src:/var/www/docker_sandbox  <== VOLUME
        ...
        networks:
            - docker_sandbox_net
        depends_on:
            - php
    mysql:
        ...
volumes:
    docker_sandbox_src:
networks:
    docker_sandbox_net:
        driver: bridge
```

One possible solution is to use a named volume that connects the nginx service with the symfony service. The problem with that is that on an update of our symfony image the volume keeps the old changes. So there is no update until we manually delete this volume.

Is there a better way to handle this issue? May be a volume that is able to overwrite its content when a new image is deployed. Or an nginx config that does not require the symfony source code in its own container.

Comment: You can build a second image `FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine`, and `COPY` in the artifacts you need.

Comment: Your’re right, that would work. The only negative thing on this solution ist hat i will have another container (that uses a lot of disk space) for every environment, instead of pulling the standard image.

Comment: Until now I „solved“ this problem by using a shell script for the deployment. This script stops and removes the docker containers, deletes the volume that contains the “old data”, pulls the new image and starts the docker stack again. Not the very best solution but it works.